# Intended HTML content of the added devtools panel is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to add a new devtools panel using my Chrome extension. I added `devtools_page` to `manifest.json` and was able to add a new panel to the Devtools, but I can't see the HTML content. When the panel is opened, I only see this.
[image]

**manifest.json**

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html",
```

**devtools.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./devtools/devtools.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**devtools.js**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
    "Demo panel",
    "panel.png",
    "demo_panel.html",
    function (panel) {
      console.log("Panel created: ", panel);
    }
);
```

The folder structure is as follows.

[image]

How can I show the HTML content of `demo_panel.html` under ***Demo Panel*** panel? Thanks for all helpful answers.

Comment: Check the errors on chrome://extensions page and maybe use `/devtools/` prefix in paths you provide in create().

Comment: @wOxxOm Surprisingly, there are no errors appearing in the extensions page. I will try adding a prefix to paths as you've recommended.